# C# ArrayList calling on a constructor class

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, arraylist

I'm aware that an ArrayList is probably not the way to go with this particular situation, but humor me and help me lose this headache.

I have a constructor class like follows:

```
class Peoples
    {
        public string LastName;
        public string FirstName;
        public Peoples(string lastName, string firstName)
        {
            LastName = lastName;
            FirstName = firstName;
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to build an ArrayList to build a collection by calling on this constructor.  However, I can't seem to find a way to build the ArrayList properly when I use this constructor.  I have figured it out with an Array, but not an ArrayList.

I have been messing with this to try to build my ArrayList:

```
ArrayList people = new ArrayList();
            people[0] = new Peoples("Bar", "Foo");
            people[1] = new Peoples("Quirk", "Baz");
            people[2] = new Peopls("Get", "Gad");
```

My indexing is apparently out of range according to the exception I get.

Comment: And whilst your at it change Peoples to Person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be:

```
people.Add(new Peoples(etc.));
```

instead of

```
people[0] = new people()...;
```

Or better yet:

```
List<People> people = new List<People>();

people.Add(new People);
```

Just to be complete.  Using a straight array:

```
People[] people = new People[3];

people[0] = new People();
```

Comment: great, thanks!  sorry that I haven't quite figured out how to format my posts yet.  if anybody could send me a message with some tips, that'd be great.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  The only reason for doing it this way is that it's for a school project, and I'm required to go through all the different types (Array, ArrayList, List, etc.).  But I greatly appreciate the tips on the better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

Try `people.Add(new Peoples("Bar", "Foo");`

Answer (score 3):

You should add elements to the list. Like the following

```
ArrayList people = new ArrayList(); 
people.Add(new Peoples("Bar", "Foo"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do

```
people.Add (new Peoples("Bar", "Foo"));
people.Add (new Peoples("Quirk", "Baz"));
people.Add (new Peoples("Get", "Gad"));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you attempt to call people[i] without first populating the array list you will get the IndexOutOfRangeException. You must first add to the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(new Peoples("Bar", "Foo"));
```

You can then access the list by the index which would be done in a foreach or for loop.

Is there a reason you are not using `List<Peoples>` which would give you a strongly typed collection? 
Also, you have publicly accessible fields in the class although I realise you probably just threw together that code for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [ArrayList.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) function to add to the array list.

```
ArrayList peoplesArray = new ArrayList();
peoplesArray.Add(new Peoples("John","Smith");
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, ArrayList is considered evil by many.  As Kevin said, it would be better to us List<People>.

List is what is called a generic.  Google 'strongly typed', 'boxing', and 'generics' for a better understanding of why.

back to your original question:
An array's size must be declared when instantiated, i.e. 
People[] people = new People[5];

this creates 5 empty cells in the array so you can access the cells using a subscript i.e. [0]

An ArrayList or List<T> when instantiated using the default constructor has no cells i.e.
List<People> people = new List<People>();

people[0] does not exist at this point.

use people.Add(new People("first", "last")); to add a new cell to the list.  now the subscript [0] is valid, but [1] is still invalid because there is only one cell.

A list i.e. ArrayList or List can grow dynamically by using .Add().  Once added to a list, you can reference them using the subscript [i], but you cannot use the subcript to add them.